# How To Setup a DAG and Link to a Cobrand?

Tags: api, rest, testing, directed-acyclic-graphs, yodlee

We were given an Rest API as a client of Yodlee.
And we want to test using DAG.
We wanted to test the API and we are successful at calling coblogin.

How does one link the DAG to our assigned Cobrand credential?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, we are able to use  coblogin via REST.
Now we want to test fetching pre-populated transactions.  We hope DAG can help us in building our REST calls. Or are we looking at a wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a user on Yodlee platform and then use DAG to add an account. Then you can call the dataservice APIs to get the data.

Please go through the below documentations -

[Quick Start Guide](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Quickstart/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide)

[API reference](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference)

[API flow](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow)

Also you can a dag account using Yodlee's provided UI called FastLink and then use API to extract data. You can request Yodlee for providing access to that.

Comment: Hi.  I have already populated a DAG Test Catalog via Yodlee's site.
But how are these DAG to be connected from the Cobrand credential given us?  (DAG already have user and password indicated.)